# Setting welcome message on server?

Tags: windows-registry, windows-server-2003-r2

I'd like to set a welcome message for all users to see for an information notice, on Windows Server 2003 R2. `LegalNoticeCaption` and `LegalNoticeText` are already used for legal reasons, so I'd like to use `Welcome` regkey as noted here: http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/Windows2000/RegistryTips/Miscellaneous/LogonBanner-DisplayingWarningMessage.html

But when I navigate to this regkey path, I do not see any `Welcome` key. Any ideas?

I've tried adding `Welcome` with a value of "This is a test" and nothing happened

Comment: Have you tried just creating the key ?

Comment: In addition to Andre's suggestion, Server 2003 goes EoL on July 14th of this year, so where ever possible, your efforts should be concentrated on migrating off of Server 2003, and not implementing new features on your 2003 Server(s).

Comment: @HopelessN00b The message is about the migration.

Comment: @AndréDaniel No, not something I like to just poke on a prod server (and I don't have another 2003 server to test on)

Comment: The registry works as a key value store, and the system only accesses the keys it needs and knows about, so there is very little risk to break anything by *creating a new key*. You can even create a key with a random name and value and the system won't care.

Comment: @AndréDaniel I gave it a shot, added the key with a value "This is a test". Logging off and back on, it didn't appear.

Comment: Yeah so it didn't work, either you need to restart something (not sure how you're gonna do that on a production server) or the key just has no effect on Server 2003.